# how to install matlab from iso file in linux without root permission?

Tags: linux, iso-image, extract, matlab

I have an ISO file of MATLAB and I want to extract it to be able to run the installer. I'm not the admin of the computer and there is no 7-zip or file-roller. It has isoinfo but I don't how to use it to extract the whole ISO file and apparently I cannot mount the ISO too. Do you guys know any other way to extract the iso file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install 7zip (to your home), fuseiso, mountlo and other tools and unpack.

For example, here's stand-alone "7za" for linux for you: http://vi-server.org/vi/_/7za